# Using DISM in code

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8, command-prompt

I've been searching to try and find out if its possible to access DISM or any of its command-lets in any form of programming language. I know DISM can be accessed through both powershell and the standard command prompt, but i require that these commands be executed from a program that i am developing.

The program i am developing would require me to be able to remove/uninstall windows 8 apps. From my searching online, DISM seems to be the most 'low-level' way of doing this.

Removing Windows 8 Apps in powershell: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Windows-Store-Apps-a00ef4a4

Is it possible to access DISM in code or is it just a pipe dream?

Comment: Unclear questions. Are you developing a c# application? If so, you can use powershell and pipelines in c# to use the `Remove-AppxPackage` cmdlet etc. There's also an API for this I think. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the API is around and in use (ask Nuhi), it's compatible with C,C++, here is a link to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824790.aspx

But ps1 is simple enough, why not ps.invoke, much easier and will take you less lines of code.

```
dism /Image:c:\offline /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Bing_1.2.0.137_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:c:\offline /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingFinance_1.2.0.135_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:c:\offline /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingMaps_1.2.0.136_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```